# Symfony2 - what to watch out for when running a controller on the command line Vs browser

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I'm about to start writing a Symfony2 application and I've come across some notes I must have written a while back about ensuring I write Symfony2 controllers with the fact it needs to be ran from the command line too.

Rather than bash out a load of controllers and seemingly be happy they work in a web browser, I want to ensure all controllers work on the command line too.

A lot of them will need to be ran from the command line, e.g. Cron Tasks etc.

(1) My notes tell me to insert this in AppKernel.php:

```
            * This prevents a  'You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request")'  error

            <?php

                class AppKernel extends Kernel
                {

                    protected function initializeContainer() {
                        parent::initializeContainer();
                        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
                            $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
                            $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
                        }
                    }

                }

            ?>
```

(2) I've also got a pre-written request listener that runs various code on every request, and I'm aware the variables generated won't be used on the command line.

(3) I know that none of my Apache config will run (as it's not running inside Apache), and I also know that there's two php.ini files (CLI and Apache).

What else do I need to consider?

What else isn't available on the command line compared to a browser?

Comment: My 2 cents... The biggest one for me is sending emails.. With browser I believe it is handled on kernel terminate (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event) but with CLI you have to handle the sppol and what not yourself like so http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#using-memory-spooling

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Symfony 2 has a build in interface for creating CLI based commands that will have the entire application bootstrapped, it's called [Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Build out your cronjobs and tasks using this and you can use dependency injection to ensure you have all of the services you need.

I'm sure with some research you could figure out how to load a controller if necessary--controller forwarding or [virtual](https://www.php.net/virtual)?